# How to execute a python script from Java?

Tags: java, python

I have a python script and need to run the python script from Java. How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: @SAJ: The above comment looks like sarkasm, but it is well intended ;)

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use [jython](http://www.jython.org/) (Python written in Java).

If that's not appropriate, you can fork/exec your script process using [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). Using this can be a bit fiddly, however - check out [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) for common gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to jython, [python.org](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#Java) lists also Jepp as a possible choice.

Comment: I think *JPype* isn't here the right choice. JPype is "Java in Python", not "Python in Java". But *Jepp* (http://jepp.sourceforge.net/) would be work like expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python script_name.py")
```